# Can I stream a processed video output from OpenCV on my PC to an Android tablet?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, video

I am using C++ on a Windows 7 computer and a 2013 Google Nexus 7.  I am hoping to take a video stream from the tablet's camera, send it to the computer like an IP webcam, process it, and then send the processed video back to the tablet all in real time or near-real time.  Is this possible?  How would I do it?  I was thinking that if I can output opencv into vlc that I can potentially stream that to the tablet, but I have no idea how I would do that either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: using libvlc (for sending) seems to be a good idea already to me. opencv *can* handle the receiving side(VideoCapture(url), and that works due to calling ffmpeg) . but there's good reason, to tunnel even further, and use gstreamer directly (for sending)

Comment: oh, wait, if the (receiving)tablet is running andoid, that's bad. you'd need to coome up with your own ffmpeg wrapper then

Comment: @berak what would be better than running android?

Answer (score 0):

why you wouldn't use the opencv for android (it is java though) and process it on the tablet? that isn't an option?

if you would connect them via wi-fi, upload and download in parallel won't be smooth, so some buffering should be provided to overcome that.

Comment: Like i said, the idea is for a remote user on a computer decide what processing happens with a user interface.